# How to configure WSO2 API Manager to an external Identity Provider?

Tags: saml, wso2, wso2-api-manager

All,

I'm trying to configure the wso2 product with an external IDP, not the IS IDP. What configuration files need to updated and with what information? Also, when I add an IDP from the API Manager browser, where is that file being saved server-side and is it being used?

Thanks,
Hunter

Comment: How can I point the software at an external IDP without using the Identity Server. I currently do not have that product installed. Is there a way to move forward without it?

Answer (score 1):

If your IDP supports saml you can configure it as federated IDP in APIM directly. If your IDP does not support saml , plug wso2 IS between APIM and your IDP and configure  your IDP as federated IDP in wso2 IS.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add an external IDP, you can use WSO2 Identity Server to bridge the external IDP to API Manager. I believe [this](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/03/bring-your-social-identity-to-perform-organizational-authorization-actions-with-wso2-identity-server/) article will be helpful to figure out the design and configuration for you solution. [This](http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2014/07/leveraging-federation-capabilities-of-identity-server-to-api-gateway/) webinar and related [blog](http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.com/2014/07/leveraging-federation-capabilities-of.html) to the same, would help too.

Comment: Also look at the answer to following SO question,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062588/wso2-api-manager-with-stormpath-instead-of-wso2-is

Comment: Thanks for the post Lahiru! How can I point the software at an external IDP without using the Identity Server. I currently do not have that product installed. Is there a way to move forward without it?

Answer (score 0):

I have made wso2 am 1.10.0 work with PingFederate saml2 (with and without IS, now without IS), for the majority of it. [How to integrate WSO2 API Manager (AM) 1.10.0 with PingFederate SAML 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38176390/how-to-integrate-wso2-api-manager-am-1-10-0-with-pingfederate-saml-2-0).

I followed the instructions here https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Configuring+Single+Sign-on+with+SAML2 - just assuming WSO2 IS as PingIdentity. For the mojority part it's working, but I cannot generate keys when subscribing to an API. It says "invalid credentials" even if I have logged into applications and subscriptions and can create applications from /store UI.