# WSO2 API Manager with Stormpath instead of WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Has anyone attempted to do this, as in use stormpath as the identity server with WSO2 API Manager instead of WSO2s Identity Server?

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to connect the stormpath identity server directly. but you can plug that identity server to wso2 identity server and use it. You will have to create a custom federated authenticator for this

see https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Federated+Authentication . Default pack contains federated authenticator for facebook, yahoo, google, etc. Document describes about that and also provide instructions on how to create a custom federated authenticators